# Hyperledger Cello vs Minifabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-cello, minifab

I am a newcomer to the Hyperledger world. While exploring the options to build the blockchain network, I came to the two options.

1. Hyperledger Cello
2. Minifabric (https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/minifabric/)

Both the projects are under the hyperledger-labs repo.
I like to understand the purposes of these 2 projects, I looking for an option that can help me to focus on the application layer/Chaincode rather than messing into the multihost network management.

---

by the way at last I need to deploy the project on production. Possibly I will be using on-premises machines and cloud VMs both. Also, I am looking for options to lay down the production network as well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent response by Kekomal, you might also want to consider looking at the free IBM Blockchain Platform extension for VSCode (can be found in the VSCode extensions marketplace). This is designed to help you focus on the application/chaincode layer and provides an inbuilt fabric you can use for testing

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, use Minifabric. I find it the simpler, faster and lighter way to start your development network to test your chaincodes.

Cello is more oriented to build and maintain your pre-production or production network as a service.

By the way, there is a third option that is building your network from Fabric docker images and Fabric tools, which is the best method to learn how your Fabric network really works. But, for your purpose, I would use Minifabric.